# Iterate over values which are arrays with ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

given the following object:

```
{
    key1: ["val1","val2","val3","val4"],
    key2: ["val2","val5","val22","val4","val8","val1"],
    key3: ["val1"],
    key4: ["val11","val12"]
}
```

Is it possible to iterate over all the values in one time using ng-repeat?

My motivation is:
1. I use ng-repeat in a `<tr>` tag, which CANNOT be placed in the `<tbody>` and i need to create a row in the table for each value e.g:

```
<tr>
    <td>key1.val1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>key1.val2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>key1.val3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>key1.val4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>key2.val2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>key2.val5</td>
</tr>
... and so on ...
```

2. I do not know the keys or value in advanced. I get them through an API

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like you need to the key at all, so just concatenate all the arrays together.  Loop through the available keys (properties of the object) and use something like `angular.extend()`.

Comment: I think the simplest solution fits best. Just transform your data structure in a simple list and use just one ng-repeat on `<tr>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your keys are properties of an object I would convert it to an array in a first step:

```
$scope.keys = [];
for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
         $scope.keys.push(object.property);
    }
}
```

Then you may display all values with a nested ng-repeat directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="key in keys">
   <div ng-repeat="val in key[$index]">
      {{val}}
```

**Edit**: There's also a way to iterate over the object properties directly

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
```

Like documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

Comment: my solution was like your last example:
`ng-repeat="(key,table) in ::schemesAndTables"`

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.allValues = [];
angular.forEach(object, function(array) {
    array.forEach(function(value) {
        $scope.allValues.push(value);
    });
});
```

Then simply use an ng-repeat on `allValues`.